# How to Route Messages to Microservice Instances Dynamically Based on Key/Value?

Tags: microservices, reverse-proxy, messagebroker

I'm building a system where client IoT devices will be making persistent websocket connections to a single instance of a microservice. We'll call it the "hardware gateway". End devices will be connecting to one of these service instances and may migrate between services at anytime (perhaps due to a reboot or network interruption).

Other services will be pushing notifications to these hardware clients via some hardware gateway instance. I need a way to route these requests to the specific instance that is maintaining a connection to a specific IoT device. At the moment, my solution is to maintain an external KV store where I can map an IoT device's UUID to a service instance, but that puts an extra dependency on all other services to know about this KV store. Not to mention the additional latency introduced by this query.

Maybe there's some reverse proxy that allows me to dynamically update its matching criteria? I've also looked into using a message broker like RabbitMQ, but it doesn't seem to support this use case.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reasonable solution in JVM land for this: Akka.

The instances form an Akka cluster.  When a device makes a websocket connection, an actor is spawned to handle the interactions over the websocket.  The actor registers that it is the actor interacting with the device with a cluster sharded actor keyed by the device's ID (and likely periodically reregisters with the sharded actor).  As instances are deployed, etc. the cluster rebalances.  An important feature of this is that the service is stateful, but the instances deploy in a way that looks to the outside world like it's stateless: requests can go to any node.

For pushing notifications to the devices, the HTTP endpoint or message-bus consumer in the service looks up the cluster sharded actor which forwards the notification to the websocket actor (you'll want to think about whether you want at-least-once or at-most-once delivery, which will govern whether there's some portion of the cluster sharded actor which should be persistent).